# sp_executesql must declare variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL code

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnF VARCHAR(100)
        @ColumnLoop INT = 3

SET @Query = N'SELECT @ColumnF=[F'+CAST(@ColumnLoop AS VARCHAR)+'] 
               FROM [Prestage].[SurveyBulkCrosstab] 
               WHERE ExcelRowNumber = 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query;
```

And I am getting the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable sql @ColumnF

I'm not sure how to solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the docs, you have to pass the parameter into `sp_executesql` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this as:

```
DECLARE @Query   NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ColumnF VARCHAR(100),
        @ColumnLoop INT = 3;

SET @Query = N'
SELECT @ColumnF=[F'+CAST(@ColumnLoop AS VARCHAR(255))+'] 
FROM [Prestage].[SurveyBulkCrosstab]
WHERE ExcelRowNumber = 1';

EXEC sp_executesql @Query,
                   N'@ColumnLoop INT, @ColumnF VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT',
                   @ColumnLoop=@ColumnLoop, @ColumnF=@ColumnF OUTPUT;
```

That is, you need to pass the variables into `sp_executesql`.